# Avoiding spaghetti code in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Probably a stupid question, but here goes.  In my view, I have the following code....

```
   <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Learner.MvcApplication.ViewModels.PagerViewModel>" %><% 

for (int i = Model.StartPage; i <= Model.EndPage; i++)
{
    %>
    <% =Html.Label(ViewData.Model.Controller + i.ToString()) %>
    <%
} %>
```

Do I have to close and reopen around the call to Html.Label "%><%" etc.?

I'd much rather do something like...

```
for (int i = Model.StartPage; i <= Model.EndPage; i++)
{
    Html.Label(ViewData.Model.Controller + i.ToString());
}
```

...but the labels aren't being displayed.

Can you guess that I'm new to this??

Many thanks,

ETFairfax.

Comment: And the award in Topic-Naming goes to.. *Drumroll*..... someone else.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`<%=x %>` is just a shortcut for `Response.Write(x)`:

```
for (int i = Model.StartPage; i <= Model.EndPage; i++)
{
    Response.Write(Html.Label(ViewData.Model.Controller + i.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: @AnthonyWJones, I thought that the code is pretty self explanatory. A single line of code is worth thousand words, but I agree with you that some explanatory text could be helpful in this case.

Comment: +1 but don't you mean %><%=x%><% is a shortcut for Response.Write(x); OR <%=x%> is a shortcut for <$Response.Write(x);%> ? ;)

Comment: @Anthony, you are totally correct, I've updated my post. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

This is just a short-tag `<%=`  for `<% Response.Write`  note the difference between `<%` and `<%=`

So you could very well write it like this:

```
for (int i = Model.StartPage; i <= Model.EndPage; i++)
{
    Response.Write(Html.Label(ViewData.Model.Controller + i.ToString()));
}
```

One could argue which is nicer..

Answer (score 4):

The key here is to understand the difference between <% some code %> and <%= some code %>.  <% some code %> means just execute "some code". <%= some code %> means execute some code and put the return value in the response. This is why Darin's answer above works by using Response.Write.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer has already been given (at least twice).  However some subtlies are worth pointing out. Fundementally,

```
<% stuff here %>
```

means execute the contained **statements** represented by "stuff here" using the default language. Whereas:-

```
<%=stuff here %>
```

means evaluate the contained **string expression** represented by "stuff here" using the default language and send the result to the response.

Here is a common gotcha.  Is this:-

```
<%="Hello, World!"%>
```

the same as this:-

```
<%Response.Write("Hello, World!")%>
```

?

Ans: no.  Note the first is an expression and is not terminated with a ;.  Whereas the second is a statement and will be a syntax error.  It has the ; missing.

Answer (score 2):

Also consider a switch to [Razor view engine](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx).  You can get rid of those pesky <% %>

```
for (int i = Model.StartPage; i <= Model.EndPage; i++)
{
    %>
    <% =Html.Label(ViewData.Model.Controller + i.ToString()) %>
    <%
} %>
```

becomes

```
@for (int i = Model.StartPage; i <= Model.EndPage; i++)
{        
    Html.Label(ViewData.Model.Controller + i.ToString())        
}
```

Comment: Or you could just do

<%
for (int i = Model.StartPage; i <= Model.EndPage; i++)
{
    Response.Write(Html.Label(ViewData.Model.Controller + i.ToString()));   
} %>

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion is to create a custom HtmlHelper that would take the Start and EndPage as parameters. In the Helper you should do something like this:

```
 public static string Pager<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Func<TModel, string> Prefix, int StartPage, int EndPage) where TModel : class
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (var i = StartPage; i <= EndPage; i++)
            builder.Append(html.Label(Prefix.Invoke(html.ViewData.Model) + i));

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Test (note that I am using MvcContrib TestControllerBuilder and RhinoMocks :

```
[Test]
        public void Pager_should_be_ok()
        {
            var testBuilder = new TestControllerBuilder();
            var controller = new TestController();

            testBuilder.InitializeController(controller);

            var viewData = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IViewDataContainer>();
            viewData.ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary
            {
                Model = new TestObject { Key = "Test", Value = "Value" }
            };

            var viewContext = new ViewContext { RouteData = new RouteData(), RequestContext = controller.ControllerContext.RequestContext };
            var html = new HtmlHelper<TestObject>(viewContext, viewData);

            var output = html.Pager(x => x.Key, 1, 2);

            Assert.That(output, Is.EqualTo("Test1Test2"));
        }
```

Then in your view you can use this like that:

```
<%= Html.Pager(x => x.Controller, Model.StartPage, Model.EndPage) %>
```

So this is avoiding the spaghetti code that you don't want to see and this is testable.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I had no Html.Label extension method, so mine is very simple:

public static string Label(this HtmlHelper html, string input)
        {
            return input;
        }